# The stack $\operatorname{GL}_2/B$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, stacks, rigid-analytic-geometry, representable-functors

Let $F$ be the functor from the category of affinoid Tate algebras over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ to the category $\mathrm{Sets}$, which maps an affinoid $\operatorname{Spm} R$ to the set of orbits $\operatorname{GL}_2(R)/B(R)$, where $B(R)$ is the standard Borel subgroup (upper triangular matrices).

Is the functor $F$ representable by a sheaf?

I think that the answer should be no, because if $R_1 = \mathbb{Q}_p[[t]]$, then the orbits of the following pair of $\operatorname{SL}_2(R_1)$ matrices under right multiplication by $B(R_1)$ are disjoint
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
(1-t)^{-1}& 0\\
1& 1-t
\end{pmatrix},\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0\\
1& 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
however, if $R_2 = \mathbb{Q}_p$ and $R_1 \longrightarrow R_2$ is the $\mathbb{Q}_p$ ring homomorphism sending $t$ to $0$, then the two cosets become identical.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Do you intend to switch from $\operatorname{GL}_2$ to $\operatorname{SL}_2$?  Also, I don't know what "$\mathbb Q_p$ ring homomorphism" means.  Should it be "$\mathbb Q_p$-*algebra* homomorphism"?

Comment: Actually the answer is yes to both questions